# How to access parent of object passed to a function in jquery

Tags: jquery, function, parent

I have something like the following:

```
<div id="container">
</div>

var img = $("<img/>")
        .attr("src", "http://www.rv-trips.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/olympicnationalpark-2.jpg")
        .load(function() {
            $("#container").append($(this));
        })

function someFunction(something) {
    something.parent().hide();
}

someFunction(img);
```

And it doesn't work as expected. I would like to access the parent of "img" from within the function through parent() but is doesn't work. I can however hide the image itself through `something.hide();` but thats not what I want. I could obviously also pass the parent to the function but I think there must be a way to accomplish this in a way similar to the one I tried. I'm rather new to javascript and jquery and I think I miss some fundemental concept here that I would like to understand.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You just created that image, why would it have a parent ?

Comment: `load` is async.. you would need to call `someFunction` after the load in done.. Something like this.. http://jsfiddle.net/ZLDYp/

Comment: Isn't the the div the parent if I append the image to it?

Comment: @adeneo He's appending it to #container in the code, so naturally that would be the parent. The problem is `.load()` is not firing before trying to obtain `.parent()`

Comment: But you're not appending the image to the div ?

Comment: I thought I was through `$("#container").append($(this));`

Comment: `.load(function() {
            $("#container").append($(this)); someFunction($(this));
        })`

Comment: what's happened if you try : alert(something.parent()); in someFunction ?

Comment: Okay so timing is the problem. How can I insure that the function someFunction is executed after the .load()?

Comment: @user3005411 Invoke the function inside the load or just do `$("#container").append($(this)).hide();`

Comment: The load() function has been deprecated -> http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11733, as of now, it loads content with ajax.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { /*your stuff*/ });

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = $('<img/>', {
              src: 'http://www.rv-trips.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/olympicnationalpark-2.jpg'
          }).appendTo('#container');

function someFunction(something) {
    something.parent().hide();
}

someFunction(img);
```

In my opinion you should drop the onload functionality and do it like above, especially since the functionality you're trying to use has been deprecated, but I'll try this once more, and add a solution that waits for the image to load:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(this);
    someFunction(this);
}
img.src = 'http://www.rv-trips.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/olympicnationalpark-2.jpg';

function someFunction(something) {
    $(something).parent().hide();
}
```

Comment: This changes the functionality of the code... `<img>` not to be appended until loaded.

Comment: @SetSailMedia - not really, as load() used that way was deprecated in jQuery 1.8

Comment: The thing is, my script is working with the size of the image which only seems so be accessible after loaded. What are you supposed to use instead of load() ?

Comment: @user3005411  The native `onload` method, as in my answer, or if you have to use jQuery, `$('img').on('load')` as it's an event.

Comment: @adeneo...still needs to be appended within `onload`

Comment: @charlietfl - forgot that, added!

Answer (score 0):

in your example, the parent is known, you could just use

$("#container").hide();

Do you have a "better" example, where parent is not known?

Comment: Well that was, as you guessed, just an example. The function is supposed to be used on multiple images, in different containers and hide() is just what I used in my script so I could easily see wheather I got the parent or not.

Comment: console.log(something.parent) says, that the parent of something is a function, not the div object you expect.. So, the way you try it will not work.